# $B(\tau)\bigcap Y=B(\tau_{Y})$?

Tags: general-topology

$(X,\tau)$ is a topological space, $Y$ is a subset of $X$.
$B(X)=B(\tau)$ is Borel $\sigma-$algebra on $X$.

There are two ways to generate $\sigma-$algebra on $Y$.

First, $(Y,\tau_{Y})$ is a sub-topological space, and $B(\tau_{Y})$ is generated by $\tau_{Y}$.

Second, $B(\tau)\bigcap Y$ is also a $\sigma-$algebra  on $Y$.

My question is, does $B(\tau)\bigcap Y=B(\tau_{Y})$?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace $\sigma$-algebra $B(\tau)\bigcap Y$ on $Y$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\tau_Y$, since $\tau_Y$ consists of the intersections of open sets (in $X$) with $Y$. Hence we have $B(\tau) \bigcap Y \supset B(\tau_Y)$.

Conversely, $\mathcal{A} = \{ A \subset X : A\cap Y \in B(\tau_Y)\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, and it contains all open sets, hence $B(\tau) \subset \mathcal{A}$, and it follows that $B(\tau) \bigcap Y \subset B(\tau_Y)$.